Is it wrong to keep looking?
After half a year of applying, I FINALLY got an interview that led to a job offer and it was a hybrid role, which was a huge plus since my wife just headed out on a 9 month deployment with the Army.
Part of this process was the usual offer letter, request for references, I was able to negotiate a higher salary than what they initially offered and even went through a background check.
What I ran into that stood out to me was a credit check. Unfortunately, due to some financial issues related to missing over a month of work from COVID and my wife not getting the allowances she was supposed to have via her Army pay for almost half a year some not so good things popped up on our credit.
Ideally you'd pay everything you owe every month on time and in full, but when things get tight and you have to choose between food to eat, rent, utilities or a credit card bill...guess what gets left out?
Things have been well on track for over a year now, but I know they had some questions about all of this and I gave them as adequate of an explanation of what happened and what the game plan is as I possibly could.
With that being the case, in my mind, that makes this "offer" seem a little less firm. Would it be considered unprofessional or bad form if I kept applying and even interviewing for other positions?
I am extremely good at my job, I have been in IT Support for over 20 years now and I'd really hate to put all my eggs in 1 basket like this with things being a little shaky now.

They actually asked you about your credit report?  I can't believe anybody would reject reject you because of that.  If you were trying to be the VP of Finance and your report showed multiple bankruptcies, maybe but not for your job.

I'd just ask if they want to establish a start date.  That'll say a lot!

I know they had some questions about all of this - Did they actually ask you about this? - that makes this "offer" seem a little less firm - Did they actually say this to you? Why would you think the offer is less "firm"? I'm not understanding your line of thinking. Would it be considered unprofessional or bad form if I kept applying and even interviewing for other positions? - Why would it be bad form or unprofessional? You owe nothing to anyone but yourself. You have no moral or ethical obligation to this prospective employer nor any other.

This credit check, was it connected to the background check, linked to an attempt to get a security clearance. If so [edit] those facts into the question. Additionally, what field are we talking about? If it’s anything to do with finance (banking, etc) that’s relevant, you can be in debt, as long as you have the ability to pay down the debt. I guaranteed pay check from the government through being a member of the arm services is a good, although it’s unusual for someone to run a credit check, before hiring someone to be honest. That requires information that typically isn’t probably until hird

So it's an IT position,  but it's with a credit union. I was a little surprised since I'm not going to actually handle any money or perform any financial transactions. It was tied to a background check and they did ask me some questions, basically asked for an "explanation" it was very much like the process my wife went through to get her clearance when she enlisted in the Army. In fact, aside form possibly having different standards of what is acceptable,  it was exactly like that.

Until all the i's are crossed and all the t's are dotted, all the conditional items completed, and you have signed a final offer with a firm start date you don't have a new job yet.  Until that happens there's absolutely nothing wrong with continuing to look for a new job.
If you're unemployed you absolutely should keep doing so.  If you're working and are just looking to move up to a better option it's conditional, depending on how much you value the time that would be spent looking vs getting a new one as quickly as possible.

Like Dan says, "Absolutely. " Just keep in mind that if you get a really awesome offer from somebody else and  "quit your new job before you start," you will get a black mark by your name and can kiss that company goodbye.
